# Custom "nullptr", but how to understand the codes?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, nullptr

It's from Wikipedia, if our compiler don't support c++11 , we can implement one by ourselves , just like below:

```
const class nullptr_t
{
public:
    template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const
        { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const
        { return 0; }

private:
    void operator&() const;
} nullptr = {};
```

I can't understand the above codes.

----------------------update------------------

Sorry , i didn't express it clear.

```
 template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const
        { return 0; }

 template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const
        { return 0; }
```

The above codes,i don't understand the grammar.
I never see this kind of template form before.(like "operator T C::*()")

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: The code is defining a `const` variable named `nullptr` of type `nullptr_t`. The 2 implicit conversion operators allow `nullptr` to be usable anywhere a pointer can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T>
inline operator T*() const
    { return 0; }
```

means that an object of type `nullptr_t` can be implicitly converted to any (non-member) pointer type.    It is simply an `operator T *()` function (conversion to type `T *`) templated for any type `T`.

```
template<class C, class T>
inline operator T C::*() const
    { return 0; }
```

means that an object of type `nullptr_t` can be converted to a pointer to a non-static member of any class (template parameter `C`)  of any type (template parameter `T`).

Both operators are `const`, so cannot change the `nullptr_t` object.